# Mariadb table defragmentation using OPTIMIZE

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, defragmentation

We are running MariaDB v 10.1.30, testing a script to run database maintenance script for defragmenting tables and rebuilding indexes using OPTIMIZE TABLE command by using the new 10.1.1 patch of setting innodb_defragment = 1.

I've tested Alter Table with Alogorithm = INPLACE, works fine but I'm trying to make use of innodb_defragment and use optimize to avoid creating temp files when the tables are being rebuilt as done by Alter table INPLACE algorithm.

On using Optimize, there are no temp tables created however the table gets locked not allowing concurrent connections which is not the case with Alter Table with Alogorithm = INPLACE, the documentation however mentions that the optimize is done using INPLACE algorithm.

https://mariadb.org/defragmenting-unused-space-on-innodb-tablespace/

Is this a bug or am i missing something here, please advise.

Comment: You probably should write a bug report.  Meanwhile, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and the defragmentation it does, is almost never needed.  Why do you want to use it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I was trying to get the best option to set  up a database maintenance to clear fragmented tables  using the Online DDL method, I came across this new addition and wanted to gauge which suits better, one more main intention was to have a index rebuild done on some of the tables online.

Comment: My opinion on `OPTIMIZE TABLE`:  Never do it for InnoDB tables.

Comment: @rick-james Why not?

Answer (score 2):

**The benefit for *speed* is virtually nil.**

- A "point query" (where you have the key and can go directly to the row) depends on the depth of the BTree.  For a million rows, the depth will be about 3.  For a *trillion* rows, about 6.  Optimizing a table is very unlikely to shrink the depth.
- A "range scan" (`BETWEEN`, `>`, etc) walks across a block, looking at each row.  Then it hops (via a link) to the next block until it has found all the rows needed.  Sure, you will touch more blocks in an un-optimized table, but the bulk of the effort is in accessing each row.

**The benefit for *space* is limited.**

- An `INSERT` may add to a non-full block or it may split a full block into two half-full blocks.  Later, two adjacent, somewhat empty, blocks will be merged together.  Hence, a BTree naturally gravitates toward a state where the *average* block is 69% full.  That is, the benefit of `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for *space* is limited.
- Phrased differently, `OPTIMIZE` might shrink the disk footprint for a table to only 69% of what it was, but subsequent operations will just grow the table again.
- If you are using `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, then `OPTIMIZE` cannot return the free blocks to the Operating system.  Such blocks can be reused for future `INSERTs`.

**`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is *invasive*.**

- It copies the table over, locking it during the process.  This is unacceptable to sites that need 100% uptime.
- If you are using replication, subsequent writes may stack up behind the `OPTIMIZE`, thereby making the Slave not up-to-the-second.

**Big DELETEs**

- After deleting lots of rows, there may be benefit to `OPTIMIZE`, but check the 69% estimate.
- If big deletes are a common occurrence, perhaps there are other things that you should be doing.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

**History and internals**

- Old version did `OPTIMIZE` in a straightforward way:  Create a new table (same schema); copy rows into it: rename table; drop.  Writes could not be allowed.
- `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` *probably* locks a few blocks, combines them to fill up one block, then slides forward.  This requires some degree of locking.  Based on the Question, it sounds like it simply locks the whole table.
- Note that each BTree (the PK+Data, or a secondary index), *could* be 'optimized' independently.  But no command allows for doing such for just the main BTree (PK+data).  Optimizing a single *secondary* index can be done by `DROP INDEX` + `ADD INDEX`, but that loses the index.  Instead, consider do a `NOCOPY` `ADD INDEX`, *then* `INSTANT` `DROP INDEX`.  Caution:  This could impact `USE_INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX` if you are using such.

(Caveat:  This Answer applies to InnoDB, not MyISAM.)